# Filter select options based on other selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array with priorities (1, 2, 3) used as options in multiple select boxes. I want each of the priorities to be selectable only once. So if in one select box '2' is selected, it should be removed or disabled in the other select boxes.
I found a filter [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview) but it didn't get it to work in my code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <md-select ng-model="selectedPriority[$index].priority" ng-change="selectedPriority[$index].objectId = object.id" >
        <md-option ng-value="priority" ng-repeat="priority in priorities | arrayDiff:priorities:selectedPriority[$index].priority">{{ priority }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.selectedPriority = [ ];
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.priorities = ['1', '2', '3'];
    $scope.objects = [{"date": "2017-01-08", "duration": 120}, {"date": "2017-01-07", "duration": 120}]
})

.filter('arrayDiff', function() {
    return function(array, diff) {
        var i, item,
            newArray = [],
            exception = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            item = array[i];
            if(diff.indexOf(item) < 0 || exception.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
                newArray.push(item);
            }
        }

        return newArray;

    };
});
```

Here is the plunker of my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXp5kKJaFZcKdur2xueS?p=preview

Comment: could be better if you can provide a plunker/jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: I added a plunker with my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXp5kKJaFZcKdur2xueS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example using `ng-options` which uses the `disable when` expression.

[Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions):

```
label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr
```

The second "disable" is an expression that, if evaluated to true, will disable that option (you can test this out by simply replacing it with `true`). I've created an example below:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select 
      ng-options="o as o disable when second == o for o in options"
      ng-model="first"
      ng-change="change(first)">
    </select>

    <select
      ng-options="o as o disable when first == o for o in options"
      ng-model="second"
      ng-change="change(second)">
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [1, 2, 3];
    $scope.change = function(selection) {
      console.log(selection);
    }
});
```

In this example, the first ng-options directive keeps track of the ng-model of the second ng-options directive, and vice versa. If an option is equal to the value of the other's ng-model, then that value will be disabled.

The "disable when" expression is slightly different for an object data source, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) on its usage.

[Plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/2rw71g1c/3/)

Comment: But I dont have a certain number of select boxes like these two in your example. I have multiple boxes generated by number of objects and they should all be filtered if one option is selected

Comment: How would you implement this filter with variable number of select boxes?