# Angular Filter Select Options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple Select Boxes and I want their options (an array containing 1,2 and 3) to be filterd based on the selection of the other boxes.

If "1" is selected in one box, then the other boxes should only display an array with the options "2", and "3" and so on.

I already wrote a filter but it's not fully working.
For example: If in one box "1" is selected, "1" is removed only from the options-array of this box but it should be removed in the other boxes and stay visible in the one that it is selected.

My problem is demonstrated fully in this code snippet and on http://plnkr.co/edit/COROt6ihHgyhe8jyErry?p=preview

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.selectedPriority = [ ];
    $scope.priorities = ['1', '2', '3'];
    $scope.objects = [{id:1}, {id:2},{id:3}];

})

.filter('arrayDiff', function() {
        return function(array, diff) {
            var i, item,
                newArray = [];

            for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                item = array[i];
                if(diff != item) {
                    newArray.push(item);
                }
            }
            return newArray;
        };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <select ng-model="selectedPriority[$index].priority">
                <option ng-value="priority" ng-repeat="priority in priorities | arrayDiff:selectedPriority[$index].priority">{{ priority }}</option>
            <select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41929349/4020932

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter select options based on other selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925064/filter-select-options-based-on-other-selection)